# Partial sum with SUM and INDEX

Tags: google-sheets, sum, spreadsheet

As you can see in the screenshot bellow I have wrote the following formula to calculate the partial sum from row 3 to 11:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A1:A15,E1):INDEX(A1:A15, E2))
```

It works but I can't explain why? It seems like I have wrote `=SUM(3:11)` which should return `14`, but somehow it understands that I want the range not between 3 and 11 numbers, but elements in column `A` that go from row 3 to row 11. I can't understand this as in the manual of `INDEX`  we read:

> INDEX Returns the content of a cell, specified by row and column
> offset.

and this means that it returns not a reference on the cell but its content - its value. How can we explain that?

[image]

Comment: SUM(3:14) shouldn't return 14 in your case. It will sum every cell in rows 3-14 (SUM(3:14)=SUM(A3:ZZZ14)). Like SUM(A:D) would sum every cell in those columns, but not letters "A"+"D". By using INDEX and range A:A you narrow your table from A:ZZZ to A:A, so it will sum only values in A column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INDEX changes its behaviour depending on the context in which it is used. Because you have used the INDEX(...):INDEX(...) construction (i.e. either side of the range operator (:), this is interpreted to mean that you wish each INDEX to refer to a cell reference (as this is the only context in which the range operator has any meaning).

So your formula in this case resolves to `=SUM(A3:A11)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess, this is missed in the user manual. There is no any line saying that index is returning something else than the value, right?

Comment: I would not rely on the Google Sheets documentation being definitive in any sense. I would also not be surprised if what's actually going on behind the scenes is that INDEX always returns a cell reference irrespective of the situation. Consider (from your example) that typing =INDEX(A1:A15,3) into a cell is logically equivalent to typing =A3 into the cell - either way, the result is that the value found in A3 (3) is mirrored in the formula cell.

Comment: Just out of interest, the reference behaviour of Index is mentioned in the documentation for Excel 'The result of the INDEX function is a reference and is interpreted as such by other formulas. Depending on the formula, the return value of INDEX may be used as a reference or as a value.' Sometimes it's worth cross-checking but you can't always assume that functions are implemented the same way in Excel and GS of course.

Comment: The interesting thing about the quote you've just given is that it's for the 'reference form' of INDEX, which is something found in Excel but doesn't appear to be present in Google Sheets - the syntax of the Sheets implementation of INDEX corresponds to Excel's 'array form' only...